# Replaced all mdadm RAID1 drives with new, larger drives. Now can not boot from the RAID1

Tags: mdadm

I have simply replaced all of my mdadm array hard drives with some larger drives.  I then went to reboot the system and upon booting it comes up with a grub error.  I'm not sure what is needed to be done to the mdadm drives to get them to boot properly?  I followed all instructions and partitions are all the same, data is all the same, but it still will not boot up properly.

I've attempted to grub2-install, boot into old RAID drives, etc.  Nothing has worked.  Any ideas?!

Comment: Well, what is the grub error? The error usually gives you important details to find the problem. The fact that you are getting a grub error tells you grub is installed.

Comment: UUID needed to be reconfigured for the mdadm RAID /boot record.  I defined this within the rescue mode to allow it to boot up.  Then did a dracut in rescue as well to rebuild.  All good after that.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you should have to configure that, but I suppose it depends on the specific method you followed when setting up the new drives.

Comment: It's because originally the UUID was used for the /boot partition & when replacing the drive the UUID changes

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by changing UUIDs in /etc/fstab for the new drive.  Then ran dracut to make sure everything was proper.